# Polymer app-route subroute does not update with route change

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

My problem involves chaining app-route. Originally I thought this bug came from my application but I recreated it with a simple example. The issue arises from first visiting a url that matches the subroute and then changing the route so that it does not match the subroute.

I cannot use the Polymer cdn base tag because it will change the behavior of routing. If you copy and paste the code run `bower init; bower install --save PolymerElements/app-route; python3 -m http.server;` It should run the example code.

## The Problem

1. Click link to `#/tree/maple` causes routeData.collection = 'tree', subrouteData.uuid = 'maple'. *This is correct and behaves as expected*
2. Next click link to `#/tree` causes routeData.collection = 'tree', subrouteData.uuid = 'maple'. **notice nothing changes**

Notice how even though the path changed to `#/tree` **the subroute did not update**. Is this a problem with my understanding of `app-route`?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/app-route/app-route.html">
  <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
  <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-example></x-example>
</body>

</html>

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
    <app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:collection" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>
    <app-route route="{{subroute}}" pattern="/:uuid" data="{{subrouteData}}"></app-route>

    <h1>Path</h1> 
    <p>route: [[routeData.collection]]</p>
    <p>subroute: [[subrouteData.uuid]]</p>

    Visit: [In Order]
    <a href="#/tree/maple">[2] Collection [TREE] UUID [MAPLE]</a> ->
    <a href="#/tree">[1] Collection [TREE]</a> 
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "x-example",
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

### Possible Solution but not as clean

```
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:collection" data="{{listData}}" active="{{listActive}}"></app-route>
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:collection/:uuid" data="{{itemData}}" active="{{itemActive}}"></app-route>
```

It `item` would get preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experimentation shows that when the route no longer matches, `<app.route>` changes `subroute` but doesn't clear `subrouteData` (perhaps this is a bug in that element). However, `<app-route>` always sets `data` when `active=true` (i.e., the route matches), so you would have to check the `active` flag before reading `data`.

For example, you could only show an element if `active` is `true` (and remove it from the DOM when `false`):

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[subrouteActive]]" restamp>
  <my-el uuid="[[subrouteData.uuid]]"></my-el>
</template>
```

Or the element could internally skip processing if `active` is `false`:

```
<my-el uuid="[[subrouteData.uuid]]" active="[[subrouteActive]]"></my-el>

// my-el script
_processUuid: function() {
  if (!this.active) return;
  // do something with this.uuid...
}
```

Or the element could observe `active` and reset things if `false`:

```
// my-el script
_onActiveChanged: function(active) {
  if (!active) {
    // reset...
  }
}
```